# XQuery is returning "false" when false is not a field in XML?

Tags: java, xml, string, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML:

```
<personDetails>
    <person>
        <name>Mr Test</name>
        <paid>Yes</paid>
        <details>
            <detail>
                <id>12345</id>
                <address>15 Sample Street</address>
            </detail>
        </details>
    </person>
</personDetails>
```

I am trying to returning the value for `paid` when given a certain name and ID. The value being returned is "`false`" which is incorrect and not even in my XML.

Is my current query / java method correct?

**Current Query:**

```
//personDetails/person[name='Mr Test'] and //personDetails/person/details/detail[id ='S0335171']/paid/text()
```

**Current method:**

```
public String getPaidByNameAndId(String name, String id) {
        final String _Name = name;
        final String _id = id;
        return engine.new Query<String>(PERSON_COLLECTION) {

            @Override
            protected String query(Collection collection) throws Exception {
                XQueryService service = queryService();

                ResourceSet resourceSet = service.query(
                        format("//personDetails/person[name='%s'] and //personDetails/person/details/detail[id ='%s']" +
                                        "/paid/text()"
                                , StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(_Name),
                                StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(_id)
                        ));

                for (String resource : new IterableStringResources(resourceSet)) {
                    results.add(resource);
                }
                return results.get(0);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

For reference, the xQueryService I am using is:

```
org.exist.xmldb.XQueryService;
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be constructing a query using string concatenation: you leave yourself wide open to injection attacks (or just bugs). Declare external variables in your query and bind values to them from the Java API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire XPath/XQuery is indeed returning a boolean value (two values combined using `and` operator). The correct XPath/XQuery according to your explanation would be :

```
//personDetails/person[name='Mr Test' and details/detail[id ='S0335171']]/paid/text()
```

**<kbd>[`xpath demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/IDP88C006)</kbd>**

Comment: thanks, how would I alter the Java code to reflect this? I am a complete beginner to Xpath

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java. I expect it would be the `format(...)` function call, which construct the XPath expression, something like this : `format("//personDetails/person[name='%s' and details/detail[id ='%s']]/paid/text()", StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(_Name), StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(_id)
 )`

Comment: The path is correct, this has solved the issue and I have accepted answer